# If/Else is not working in selenium which i am expecting

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My code is not working what i am expecting using if else statement, default it is checking with if condition even if the "if statement" is wrong and throwing an error as :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//span[contains(text(),'Dashboard')]"}
```

It is not checking with else if statement.

## My code

```
driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(user);
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(pass);
driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();

Thread.sleep(3000);
//WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
WebElement success = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'Dashboard')]"));

WebElement failure = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(text(),'Your login attempt was not successful due to Invalid credentials!!')]"));

if(success!=null && success.getText().matches("Dashboard")) {
    System.out.println("Able to login with this credentials "+user+" "+pass);
}
else if(failure!=null && failure.getText().matches("Your login attempt was not successful due to Invalid credentials!!")) {
    System.out.println("Unable to login with this credentials "+user+" "+pass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few breakpoints would have solved this issue. The problem is not with the If/Else statements, it is with this line:

```
WebElement success=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'Dashboard')]"));
```

If you read the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) for `findElement`, it throws an error if the element you are searching for cannot be found. This is the error that you are facing, not with the if/else statement. One possible solution would be to surround findElement with a try/catch, and assign the value of success to null if an error is thrown.